# Many DataFrames in one output, how to merge. Python

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I my code:

```
def my_def():
abc_all=open('file.txt')#where file.txt is a big data with many lines
lines=abc_all.readlines()
lines=lines[4:]
```

`file.txt` look like(about 120 letters in one line, and many lines:

`AAA S S SSDAS ASDJAI A 234 33 43 234 2342999 2.31 22 33....
 SSS S D W2UUQ Q231WQ A 222 11 23 123 1231299 2.31 22 11....`

```
for line in lines:
    abcd=line[5:-34]
    abcd2 =abcd[:27]+abcd[40:]
    abc=abcd2.split()
    result=pd.DataFrame(abc)
```

and now i want to save the results but when i am using for example: `result.to_csv()` i am receiving only first line in my output file.
I have just printed `result` and like i see i am receiving each line like DataFrame , so thats the reason why my output is printing only first line.
part of `result`:

```
         0        1    2    3      4  5  6
0  22.2222 -11.1111  222  111  name1  1  l
         0        1    2    3      4  5  6
0  33.2222 -11.1111  444  333  name2  1  c
         0        1    2    3      4  5  6
0  12.1111 -11.1111  222  111  name3  1  c
```

How can i save this output like one DataFrame, or how to merge all those DataFrames to one.
Thanks for help!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read a file line by line, and add those lines (one by one) to a dataframe? You can do this in one step: `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')`.

Answer (score 0):

What about building a list of list first and then turning it into a DataFrame. It might be easier and faster:

```
results = []
for line in lines:
    abcd = line[5:-34]
    # if we know all row are the same length one split
    results.append(abcd.split())
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

As a one-liner even:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([line[5:-34].split() for line in lines])
```

ex:

```
b = [ "0  22.2222 -11.1111  222  111  name1  1  l", "0  33.2222 -11.1111  444  333  name2  1  c", "0  12.1111 -11.1111  222  111  name3  1  c"]  
df = pd.DataFrame([line.split() for line in b])
print(df)

   0        1         2    3    4      5  6  7
0  0  22.2222  -11.1111  222  111  name1  1  l
1  0  33.2222  -11.1111  444  333  name2  1  c
2  0  12.1111  -11.1111  222  111  name3  1  c
```

As stated by *@Andrew L* it might be intersting to see if the file has not a format already supported by one of the many `pandas.read_...`

EDIT: Seems like a job for `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')` and the deleting the columns you don't want / selecting the ones you want to keep

Comment: Hi, i am trying to change my code from the begining and use `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')` likeAndrew said. And also smagnan method gives me `None` for all lines on output

Comment: @Pawe I don't know what could be happening, I have been using the table you gave on you question. But I don't know what your data really looks like (e.g why the `[5:-34]`). I added an example without the `[5:-34]` for valid text. But I imagine using `read_csv` might be easier

Comment: i have edited my question please check it. i have opened this file with `pd.read_csv` and i did:`df = pd.DataFrame([line[5:-34].split() for line in lines])` but i have also one line more like: abcd2 =abcd[:27]+abcd[40:], but its only for first line, how can i do it for all ? thanks

Comment: @Pawe Seems like a job for `pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')` and the deleting the columns you don't want / selecting the ones you want to keep

Comment: Youe are right but, in the end of my lines i have empty fields and sep are not the single space, so i cant use sep=' ', and other. i need to cut the lines in a frame at the beggining ;/ . so when i am doing for example:`df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype(str).str[:-34].astype(np.int64)` i am receiving `error:pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 40 fields in line 5, saw 52`